# Solr Update Field based on another Field

Tags: solr, copy, field, atomic

I need to create a new field in my Solr database.

My data is like:

```
{
   id: "something",
   name_s: "some name"
}
```

I want to add a new field `name_t`.

The problem is I want to update the new field `name_t` with the value of `name_s`. And I want to do this to **my whole collection documents**.

I was expecting to find something like this:

```
{ id: "xxx", name_t: { add: $name_s }}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if you have all your fields with stored/docValues on, then this would work:

1. add a copyField for name_t, like

   `<copyField source="name_s" dest="name_t"/>`

   Of course, you need to have a dynamic type of *_t or a field etc.
2. use [cursorMark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results) to iterate over all docs in a efficient way
3. for each doc, trigger a reindex with [atomic update](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents), updating some field to the same current value. I think there might be a way to trigger it also by sending no op, but not sure about the details.